# Что нужно сделать чтобы работало на более старых браузеров?

Tags: jquery

Что это видео реклама и я хочу сделать, когда рекламодатель скрывает видео, скрывалось оформление для видео. Код рекламодателя у меня возможности редактировать нет!**(сделал, но для старых браузеров это не работает!)**

**Примеру: Opera 12.17**

```html
<iframe id="kod" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe> - показывает видео + style="display: none;" (скрывается) а после этого срабатывает для div +style="display: none;"
```

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var div    = document.getElementById('div');
 
new MutationObserver(function(m) {
    m.forEach(function(rec) {
        if('none' === rec.target.style.display) div.style.display = 'none';
    });    
}).observe(iframe, {
    attributeOldValue : true,
    attributes : true,
    attributeFilter : ['style']
});
```

```html
<div id="div">dfgdfg<iframe id="iframe"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вопрос такой: Как скрыть div, внутри которого лежит iframe в тот момент, когда у iframe'а появляется `style="display: none"`?

Comment: Да правильно, который код выше он работает только на новых версиях браузера, а на старых выдоит ошибку  Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: MutationObserver на третий строчки где (new MutationObserver(function(m) {)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы скрывать div, положи его содержимое в ещё один контейнер. Затем при помощи css сделай так, чтобы div свернулся до нулевой высоты при исчезновении iframe'а.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('#iframe').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#div {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  position: relative;
}

#div span {
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding-top: 1px;
  line-height: 204px;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  height: 104px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"><span>dfgdfg</span><iframe id="iframe"></iframe></div>
<button>Hide iframe</button>
```

Comment: я не знаю, как тут сделать, мешает заголовок! 
вот сайт dugtor.ru по центру видео, может у вас получится!